# Implementing Prim's algorithm with eucledian distance

Tags: python, graph

Let me straight forward put what i need.  I have an array(first representing node and second representing some value): `[[1,10],[2,8],[3,9]]`. I made another array of euclidean distance between the nodes as follows:

```
[[0,2,1],[2,0,1],[1,1,0]]
```

Now I need to implement prim's algorithm for the nodes using the euclidean matrix as the weight of edges. Please help me.

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: The first step is writing the code! do you have done it?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't written any line of code yet, you might as well be considering what a Google search would yield for "python prim algorithm":

- [Shortest Path Problems](http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/pythonds/Graphs/graphshortpath.html) has a tutorial on Prim’s Spanning Tree Algorithm
- Another implementation of [Prim’s Spanning Tree Algorithm](http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_Prims_Spanning_Tree_Data_Structure.php)  very well commented
- [prim.py](https://gist.github.com/siddMahen/8261350): Prim's algorithm in Python
- [Discussion and Python code](http://programmingpraxis.com/2010/04/09/minimum-spanning-tree-prims-algorithm/)
- Another [python source](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/python/prim.py)
- Yet another [python source](https://jlmedina123.wordpress.com/2014/05/29/prims-algorithm-in-python/)